# Android: Looping through views

Tags: android, android-layout, loops, resources

Trying to loop through my array of ImageViews, ran into the problem when it came to finding the position of the resources. The pic below shows the problem!

[image: http://i39.tinypic.com/ou2s90.png]

Does findViewById take strings? How would I go about this?

Comment: What is the ID you have in XML? No findView... only takes int.

Comment: bblock1, bblock2, bblock3 etc

Comment: I'd suggest that you read up the basics on findViewById(). The manner in which you are trying to use that method is way off from what it does.

Comment: LuxuryMode answer is the only option I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

findViewById takes an int which you reference by using the auto-generated R class to reference your resources that are statically transformed into int representations. To loop through them you'd have to do:

```
int[] myResources = {R.id.foo, R.id.bar, R.id.buzz}

for(int i = 0; i<myResources.length; i++) {
      (ImageView)findViewById(myResources[i]).setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably storing ids into integer array, if so, just use that id to fetch view from that, and findViewById takes integer as input.